# Установка Let's Encript на Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, letsencrypt, certbot

не удается поставить certbot  на debian 8

Comment: Почему не получается? Опишите полностью проблему, так (вероятнее всего) можно будет Вам помочь. А так можно подумать что угодно.

Comment: Щас придут юзеры с шильдиком "телепат" и помогут тебе. Только свой законный отпуск догуляют и придут.

Answer (score 4):

Настройка Letsencrypt на Debian 8

> Для получения сертификата я буду использовать клиент certbot.

```
echo 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' | sudo tee 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
```

...

```
apt-get update
```

Устанавливаем клиент:

```
   apt-get install certbot -t jessie-backports
```

Пример файл nginx для сайта, которому необходимо сделать сертификат.

```
   nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/test77.com.conf
```

> Добавляем в секцию server

```
   location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
   allow all;
   default_type "text/plain";
    }
```

Применяем настройки:

```
nginx -t
service nginx reload

certbot certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d test77.com
```

После завершения процесса, сертификаты будут сохранены в каталоге:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test77.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test77.com/privkey.pem;
```

Для автоматического продления сертификатов добавим в cron

```
30 2 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew --noninteractive --renew-hook "/bin/systemctl reload nginx" >> /var/log/le-renew.log
```